# Adding Lighting inside within HDRi Environment (Night scene)

Tags: modeling, rendering, node-editor, lighting, hdri

I have been trying to add some lights within HDRi environment.

I can't figure out how to illuminate a sculpture I modeled with spotlights I placed around this model.

Quite frankly, I don't know what I am doing (or doing wrong)

Your help will be much appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CLMbmQ97LfNUlcLtKh5djVM-pXdThKSJ

Best,

JP[image]

Comment: have you tried turning up the brightness of the spot lights?

Comment: Hi,  Yes I did but it doesnt seem to do anything.  FYI, the surface is reflective mirror material so.. maybe that is why.. I tried to make the glass material not 100 % reflective.  But it still doesnt really do anything..

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your .blend file, the problem is because your glass material is 0% roughness (as you mentioned above), So the spot lights are aren't being dispersed at all, if you turn up the roughness you can see the spot lights, I put a diffuse shader on instead and you could really see the spot lights better. Since no building in the world is made of perfect glass. I would recommend adding in imperfections to the glass like smudges and warp the glass slightly with normal maps. This will help the spot lights bounce around better. Or make the building with some concrete with a lot of windows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi David,  Thank you so much for your thorough investigation.  I changed the roughness of the glass and the mirror and it helped a bit.  I guess the light on the reflective materials bounces off most of the light, so the material itself doesnt shine from the light source.  Adding a smudge onto the glass will definitely do.. but I figure that is too hard for me to do at this stage.  Again,  thanks for your help.